# Azeroth core, move custom spell to correct class/spec tab of the spell book rather than general

Tags: azerothcore

I'm fairly new.  I've created a new spell in stoneharry exported both dbc and patch successfully.  I want to move this spell under the correct class/spec section of the spellbook rather than the general tab.

I've tried adding a line to skilllineability.dbc with spell and correct flags for what I want but I can't get it to change in game.  I've exported the dbc into my folder for the server and also tried exporting the mpq into the client files (Using WDBX), nothing ever changes.  Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe a tutorial how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi mbeal, there is zero support from AzerothCore's end for any change to whatever client. Feel free to reach out for anything related to the server with us.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check that the number of skillline.dbc is the skill group you want to classify. In the second column of skilllineability.dbc, check if the dbc in the database is overwritten. dbc in the database has a higher priority